# Facebook like box for page (social plugin) blank when logged in as page - real Facebook bug or not? And remedy?

Tags: facebook, facebook-integration, iframe

I've noticed that Facebook like box for a page (social plugin) is blank when I am logged into Facebook as a page that I am admin.

This happens for my page and for other sites.

When I am logged into Facebook as myself, i.e. a regular user, the Facebook like box is displayed normally. When I am not logged in, again, the page is displayed normally.

I have raised this as a bug with Facebook themselves, but is it? Is there a workaround or adjustment I need to make.

I am using standard Like Box IFrame code from Facebook themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this could be regarded (by Facebook) as a feature, rather than a bug.

I can't find it now, but am certain that I've seen a reference to it in Facebook's documentation, with a comment that the "fix" it to switch back to using FB as yourself instead of as a page.

Comment: Thanks @MaryC.fromNZ: If you can cite the documentation as a link in you answer I will accept your answer :) and also upvote it :)